# Does $a^n=b^n \implies a=b$ in an abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Does $a^n=b^n \implies a=b$ in an abelian group?

My intuition tells me this mug not always be the case. Under what conditions is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Recall Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: If you allow $G$ to be non-abelian, then this is true for torsion-free hyperbolic groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If $\,A\,$ is **any** (abelian or not) group of order $\,m\,$ , then $\,x^m=y^m=1\;,\;\forall\,x,y,\in A\,$

For the other part (now with abelian groups): try taking $\,m\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;gcd(m,|G|)=1\,\ldots$

Comment: Any idea how to proceed with the "under what conditions"? Is $\gcd(n,m)=1$ sufficient?

Comment: OK but what if I know $a^n,b^n\neq 1$?

Comment: Perhaps even more simply, for any element of order $n$ $x\in A$ we have $x^n=1^n=1$.

Comment: @misi Consider the group of nonzero reals under multiplication. Then $a^n=(-a)^n$ for any even $n$.

Comment: @misi (In an abelian group.) If $a^n=b^n$, then $1=(ab^{-1})^n$. So pick any element $x$ such that $x^n=1$, and for any $b$, set $a=bx$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(A,+)$ be an abelian group (written additively: thus instead of $x^n$ we write $nx$...)  For $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ we define

$A[n] = \{x \in A \ | \ nx = 0\}$, the **n-torsion subgroup**, and
$A[\operatorname{tors}] = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} A[n]$, the **torsion subgroup**.

Why are these relevant?  Because for $a,b \in A$, if $na  =nb$, then $n(a-b) = 0$ so $a-b \in A[n]$.  Conversely, if there is a nonzero $b \in A[n]$, then $n0 = nb = 0$. Thus:

$\bullet$ For a fixed positive integer $n$ and all $a,b \in A$, $na = nb \implies a = b$ holds iff $A[n] = 0$.

$\bullet$ For an abelian group $A$, for all $a,b \in A$ and all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, 
$na = nb \implies a= b$ holds iff $A[\operatorname{tors}] = 0$.

Another, yet cleaner, way to express this is that for any abelian group and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, multiplication by $n$ is an endomorphism of $A$ (i.e., a group homomorphism from $A$ to itself).  Then $A[n]$ is precisely the kernel of this endomorphism.  The OP is asking when the endomorphism is injective, and the answer is...if and only if the kernel $A[n]$ is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

No. (1)(1) = (-1)(-1).

For an arbitrary $n$,
if $w= e^{2\pi i/n}$,
$w^n = 1^n$.